# What does "see below" mean when used as a type or exception specification?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, typedef, noexcept

Looking through the C++ standard (<s>current</s> draft http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf, sec 20.8.3 is one such place) and through LLVM's libc++ headers, I've found "see below" used as a type and exception specification.  It seems to be used when no type exists, but it seemed strange to use a 2 word phrase for that instead of some sort of valid identifier.

Is it discussed somewhere in the standard or elsewhere?  Why/how is it used?

Comment: [Current draft is N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*see below* is simply a place holder for one of a few possible types which are always described in the following text. For example here:

> typedef *see below* element_type;
>
> 1
>
> Type: `Ptr::element_type` if such a type exists; otherwise, `T` if
>   `Ptr` is a class template instantia-tion of the form `SomePointer<T, Args>`, where
>   Args is zero or more type arguments; otherwise, the specialization is ill-formed.

you may subsitute `Ptr::element_type` or `T` if `SomePointer<T, Args>` is valid for *see below* depending on context.

This form is named a syntactic category and is described in section 1.6 of the same document.

Comment: That makes sense in the text of the standard, but it shows up in typdefes in the headers that I have (OS X's copy of LLVM libc++ atomic, memory, function, and scoped_allocator)

Comment: @BenJones Those are excerpts of the standard text included in large block comments as documentation of sorts.

Comment: ...foiled by less's lack of syntax highlighting.  Thanks.